# Как правильно использовать testImplementation?

Tags: java, android, юнит-тесты, junit, test-automation

Мне нужно написать несколько тестов, вот что то такое

```
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry
import org.junit.Assert.*
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ExampleInstrumentedTest {
    @Test
    fun useAppContext() {
        val appContext = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
        assertEquals("ent.test", appContext.packageName)
    }
}
```

Для того, что это заработало я добавил вот такую зависимость

```
testImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:${project.test.JUnit}"
```

но все подсвечивается красным, зависимсть не распознана, меняю на

```
implementation "androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:${project.test.JUnit}"
```

все работает

Насколько я понимаю, то для зависимостей тестовых нужно использовать `testImplementation`, чтоб не смешивать их с теми что пойдут в билд, но вопрос, почему когда использую `testImplementation` то зависимость не распознается?

Comment: попробовал вашу зависимость воткнуть к себе в проект - все работает штатно, попробуйте удалить папку `.gradle`, почистить проэкт, и плюс я бы тоже предложил попробовать на каком-то чистом тестовом окружение - то есть создайте свежий проект, добавьте в него эту зависимость и посмотрите будет ли ошибка, плюс попробуйте добавить ее напрямую с версией, а не с переменной окружения, ну или попробуйте `testCompileOnly `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `testImplementation` - для локальных тестов (на ПК)
- `androidTestImplementation` - для тестов на Андроиде

Код для этих тестов должен лежать в папках `test` и `androidTest`, соответственно.
Можете создать новый пустой проект - в шаблоне это всё есть с примерами обоих тестов